# How to calculate parameters in each convolution layer (CIFAR-10 dataset)

Tags: deep-learning

This is a function to create a model for input images stored in 4D tensors of 50000 x 32 x 32 x 3.

```
def createModel():
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
   model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
   model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
   model.add(Dropout(0.25))

   model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
   model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
   model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
   model.add(Dropout(0.25))

   model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
   model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
   model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
   model.add(Dropout(0.25))

   model.add(Flatten())
   model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
   model.add(Dropout(0.5))
   model.add(Dense(nClasses, activation='softmax'))

return model
```

The model summary ([attached](https://www.learnopencv.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/keras-cnn-cifar-model-summary.png)) shows that the number of parameters after the first convolution should be 896 parameters but I am not certain how they got this number. 
I was assuming the calculation should be = 32 * 3 * 3 parameters.

Can someone tell me how to calculate the parameters per convolution layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of kernel parameters in a 2D convolution is:

```
output channels * kernel width * kernel height * input channels
```

and if bias is used (`use_bias=True`) then there are an addition `output channels` bias parameters.

So your first layer has `(32 * 3 * 3 * 3) + 32 = 896` parameters

Your second layer has `(32 * 3 * 3 * 32) + 32 = 9248` parameters

Etc